# ios - resignFirstResponder not working

Tags: ios, uitextfield, modal-dialog, uitextfielddelegate, resignfirstresponder

I have a view presented modally which contains 3 label.

The third label should not be editable and should show a UIDatePicker when clicked on it, and hiding keyboard if it displayed.

So I did that :

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == _birthdateTextField) {

        _birthdateDatePicker.hidden = NO;

        if ([_firstnameTextField isFirstResponder]) {
            NSLog(@"first");
            [_firstnameTextField resignFirstResponder];
        } else if ([_lastnameTextField isFirstResponder]) {
            NSLog(@"last");
            [_lastnameTextField resignFirstResponder];
        }

        return NO;
    }

    _birthdateDatePicker.hidden = YES;

    return YES;
}
```

I can clearly see my log message ("first" or "last", depending on last focused text field) but the keyboard is still displayed.

Someone is figuring out what's the problem here ?

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but you can set your `_birthdateDatePicker` object to the `_birthdateTextField`'s `inputView` property.  If you do that, you don't really need to override `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`

Comment: Wow thx ! It's working easier like that :D Plz give an answer so i can accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having to do this complicated work with overriding `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` you can just do this somewhere, like in `viewDidLoad`:

```
_birthdateTextField.inputView = _birthdateDatePicker;
```

And the date picker will replace the keyboard when you go to edit the birthdate text field

Answer (score 4):

If you presenting modal view as UIModalPresentationFormSheet, answer is here:
[Modal Dialog Does Not Dismiss Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019709/modal-dialog-does-not-dismiss-keyboard)

[iPad keyboard will not dismiss if modal ViewController presentation style is UIModalPresentationFormSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372333/ipad-keyboard-will-not-dismiss-if-modal-view-controller-presentation-style-is-ui)