# Hide Pickers and Keyboard when Opening New TableView Controller from Text Field

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipickerview

I have a total of 5 text fields in a view controller. 1 of them opens the keyboard to fill in data. 2 of them open up the picker view to select the value. 1 opens up the Date Picker. And the last one segues to a Table View Controller.

The pickers and keyboard open up fine as I transition from one text field to another. If I click on the text field to segue to the table view, it opens as well. The problem occurs when I try to open the Table View if there is currently a picker or keyboard already active. The picker or keyboard from the previous selected text field shows in front of the table view. How do I hide the picker or keyboard before going to the table view?

Link to sample project http://www.filedropper.com/test_9

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AddAEntryViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textEntryName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textEntryStatus;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textEntryLocation;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textEntryGender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textDOB;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerAddEntryInfo;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datepickerAddEntryInfo;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "AddAEntryViewController.h"

@interface AddAEntryViewController ()

@property(strong, nonatomic)NSArray *arrayEntryStatus;
@property(strong, nonatomic)NSArray *arrayEntryLocation;
@property(strong, nonatomic)NSArray *arrayEntryGender;

@end

@implementation AddAEntryViewController{

}

@synthesize textEntryName=_textEntryName;
@synthesize textEntryStatus = _textEntryStatus;
@synthesize textEntryLocation = _textEntryLocation;
@synthesize textEntryGender = _textEntryGender;
@synthesize textDOB =_textDOB;
@synthesize pickerAddEntryInfo = _pickerAddEntryInfo;
@synthesize datepickerAddEntryInfo = _datepickerAddEntryInfo;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //TOOLBAR SETUP

    CGRect cgRect =[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGSize cgSize = cgRect.size;

    UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    toolbar.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, cgSize.width, 35);
    toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

    //PICKER SETUP

    _pickerAddEntryInfo.hidden=YES;
    _arrayEntryStatus = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Single",
                     @"Married", nil];
    _arrayEntryGender = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Female",@"Male",  nil];

    _textEntryStatus.inputView = _pickerAddEntryInfo;
    _textEntryGender.inputView = _pickerAddEntryInfo;

    _textEntryStatus.inputAccessoryView=toolbar;
    _textEntryGender.inputAccessoryView=toolbar;


    //DATEPICKER SETUP

    _datepickerAddEntryInfo.hidden=YES;

    [_datepickerAddEntryInfo setMaximumDate:maxDate];
    [_datepickerAddEntryInfo setMinimumDate:minDate];
    [_datepickerAddEntryInfo setDate:startDate];

    _textDOB.inputView = _datepickerAddEntryInfo;
    _textDOB.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
}

 #pragma mark - Text Field Editing Begins

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //Picker - these text fields open up the Picker View
    if (_textEntryStatus.editing == YES ||  _textEntryGender.editing == YES)
    {
        _pickerAddEntryInfo.hidden=NO;
    }

    //DatePicker - this text field opens up a Date Picker
    if (_textDOB.editing == YES)
    {
        _datepickerAddEntryInfo.hidden=NO;
    }

    //TableView for Entry Location - This text field will segue to a Table View Controller populated with data
    if (_textEntryLocation.editing == YES)
    {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}


 #pragma mark - Text Field Editing Ends

-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: What about sending `resignFirstResponder` to that textField when performing segue to the tableView?

Comment: I applied resignFirstResponder to that textField in order to hide the Keyboard from opening for editing. It does not hide any of the Pickers or the keyboard from the other textField.

Answer (score 0):

Use `prepareForSegue:` to perform any actions before segueing to another view controller.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueToMyTableView"]) {

        // send resignFirstResponder to all textFields
        [textEntryName resignFirstResponder];
        [textEntryStatus resignFirstResponder];
        [textEntryLocation resignFirstResponder];
        [textEntryGender resignFirstResponder];
        [textDOB resignFirstResponder];

        // and remove all pickers views from the superview
        [pickerAddEntryInfo removeFromSuperview];
        [datepickerAddEntryInfo removeFromSuperview];

    }
}
```

You can assign name to your segue in Storyboard like this (don't forget to select it on scheme)

[image]

Related documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue:sender:).

Comment: What do you mean by "select it on scheme"? I tried your advice but still not working. I am able to pass a NSLog to tell me that the segue will occur but the resignFirstResponder action does not hide the pickers or keyboard from the other textFields.

Comment: @ObjCNoob I mean select segue itself (sorry if it sounds too obvious).
Ok, are there not only one keyboard/picker need to be hidden during segue? If yes, then you need to call `resignFirstResponder` for other textFields too and `removeFromSuperview` for pickers. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: I tried that as well. Still a no go. I have a simple sample project where I have recreated the issue but I am not sure how to upload it on here.

Comment: I have provided a link to the sample project in my initial post.

Comment: Well I have played a bit with your test project and the thing I've noticed is that you're using a modal presentation segue. Unfortunately, Apple made it impossible to send `resignFirstResponder` messages in this case. However, there is a similar problem with solution that might be effective for your case, but I was trying to implement it in your test project and nothing helped. Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019709/modal-dialog-does-not-dismiss-keyboard).

Comment: And the last thing I can suggest you is to avoid using modal presentation in this particular case. Try to push that tableViewController instead.

Comment: Thanks for trying Vlad. Unfortunately, the push segue did not work either so I inserted a placeholder view in front of the text boxes when the pickers and keyboards are active. This seems to hide the pickers and text boxes before proceeding to the table view.