# Dismiss keyboard on IPAD

Tags: ipad, uikeyboard

The ResignFirstResponder for an UITextField on the Iphone semms to not working for the Ipad.
How can I dismiss my keyboard programmatically?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE** This answer is no longer accurate. See the [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14879832/141721).

If your UITextField is in a modal page sheet view (UIModalPresentationFormSheet), then there is (currently) no way to force the device to dismiss the keyboard [this devforums post](https://devforums.apple.com/message/166801#166801) from an apple engineer.

Answer (score 25):

In iOS 4.3, Apple introduced the above mentioned method, `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal`. It returns YES for UIModalPresentationFormSheet, preventing the keyboard from dismissing.

Overriding this method works, **but** if you present your view controller inside a UINavigationController, you must subclass UINavigationController and override the method there.

I've confirmed that this does indeed work on iOS 6. Just make sure to pay attention to the UINavigationController clause.

Comment: Also verified for iOS 7.0.

Comment: Dumb question - how to you do this if your UINavigationController is in a Storyboard in XCode 5 ?  I don't see any code ready to be changed, to use an overridden copy of this class..?

Comment: In iOS 8 you can just use `resignFirstResponder`, it'll work. You don't have to mess around with `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal` or something like that.

Answer (score 14):

[Now we can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019709/modal-dialog-does-not-dismiss-keyboard)

```
- (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal {
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: This seems to have stopped being an effective fix in iOS 6 - anyone else seeing the same?

Comment: It is not effective for me in iOS 6.0.x

Comment: vouched for... not effective in iOS 6

Comment: This used to work for viewControllers presented inside navigationControllers if you implemented the method there (obviously you need to subclass the UINavigationController). I don't know if it still does.

Comment: As of iOS 6 at least, it won't work until you override the same in a subclass of `UINavigationController`. Helped me!

Comment: Confirmed to work on iOS 7 with a subclass of UINavigationController.