# Keyboard won't dismiss when popover closes on iOS 3.2

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, keyboard, ios, iphone-sdk-3.2

```
- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    [self dismissFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}


-(void)dismissFirstResponder {
    [nameField resignFirstResponder];
    [descriptionField resignFirstResponder];
    [helpField resignFirstResponder];
 }
```

I have tried loads of different things, but the keyboard just isn't going down:

1. I checked to see if my outlets were hooked up correctly in Interface Builder
2. I put breakpoints inside the 2 methods to check they were being called at the appropriate times, and they were. Those 3 Text Fields are the only ones in the app.

What happens: The popover gets dismissed but the keyboard stays up.

I would really appreciate some help on this matter. It might be a known bug on iOS 3.2, if so any workarounds would be gratefully accepted. Thanks

Comment: Is your popover a form sheet by any chance? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372333/ipad-keyboard-will-not-dismiss-if-navigation-controller-presentation-style-is-fo

Comment: No, but there is a form sheet "below" the popover. Maybe thats it, thanks.

Comment: Actually, this seems like a more appropriate duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654474/ipad-popover-textfield-resignfirstresponder-doesnt-dismiss-keyboard

Comment: From one Tom H to another, I have submitted this as a bug report to Apple, ID# 8384423

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the delegate for UITextView the UITextField is assigned

Then call the following method to dismiss any keyboard activity from the view.

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```